# I need the query to return the amount of each ceoModel_id present in the table below, something that would look like:

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
| ceoModel_id | Qt_ceoModel |
|:----------- |------------:|
| 2           | 1           |
| 3           | 2           |
| 4           | 2           |
```

[image: original table]

Comment: The title is confusing.  Looks like what you want to do is for each id, create N rows based on the value of model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ceoModel_id, 
       count(ceoModel_id) as Qt_ceoModel
from   inventory_ceos
group by ceoModel_id;
```

This works?

Answer (score 0):

You nbeed to GROUP BY ceoModel_id

> ```
> CREATE tABLE inventory_ceos (ceoModel_id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO inventory_ceos VALUES(1),(2),(2),(3),(3)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ceoModel_id, COUNT(*) AS Qt_ceoModel  FROM inventory_ceos GROUP BY ceoModel_id
> ```
>
> ```
> ceoModel_id | Qt_ceoModel
> ----------: | ----------:
>           1 |           1
>           2 |           2
>           3 |           2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=476c0804385a11208b69264284dc8b10)*